# CruiseControl.NET and merging files. How to send log files?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

```xml
<publishers>
    <xmllogger>
        <logDir>log</logDir>
    </xmllogger>
    <merge>
        <files>
            <file action="Copy" deleteAfterMerge="false">C:\_CCNET\Aso\Artifacts\msbuild-results.xml</file>
            <file action="Copy" deleteAfterMerge="false">C:\_CCNET\Aso\Build\src\TestResult.xml</file>
        </files>
    </merge>
    <email from="xx@xx.net" mailhost="mail.xx.net" mailhostUsername="xx" mailhostPassword="xx">
        <users>
            <user name="x" group="developers" address="xx@gmail.com"/>
        </users>
        <groups>
            <group name="developers" />
        </groups>
    </email>
</publishers>
```

and `xmllogger` create folder log and save file in it with random name like `log20111229001245.xml`.

How can I merge this file to `msbuild-results.xml` and send it with mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, at least not the way you are approaching this. The standard way would be:

1. Replace your [`xmllogger`](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Xml_Log_Publisher) configuration with simple `<xmllogger/>` and put it after the [`merge`](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) publisher.
2. Unless the `msbuild-results.xml` and `TestResult.xml` files are very large, use `action="Merge"` instead of `Copy` for the merge publisher.
3. Set you [`email`](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Email_Publisher) publisher to `includeDetails="TRUE"` - once the other files are merged into you build report, that tells CruiseControl.Net to output the full build report in the email.